# PayPal Mass Payment - Python - Access Denied

Tags: python, python-2.7, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I have a Django application that needs to make mass payments to other PayPal users, I currently have PayPal Express Checkout configured and working without issue, I just am having issues with Mass Pay.

When I make the call to PayPal I am getting the following response:

```
Access Denied

You don\\'t have permission to access "http://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp" on this server.
Reference #18.7971aad1.1396129540.ab2b849 '
```

I have tried both http and https with no luck. 
Also this is the same API endpoint I use for Express Checkout without a problem.

Is there some config in PayPal Developer Panel that needs to be enabled for Mass Pay?

Thanks!

Comment: btw., considering that you are trying to hit a sandbox sever, I'm guessing you are still in testing stage, right? Do you hit this error right away or after NNN transactions?

Comment: @Qarma: Yes I have a ticket in to Paypal support but am waiting on a response.

Comment: @Qarma: Yes I am still in development, and in fact am using the same API endpoint right now to make PayPal Express Checkout payments which is working, but when I make a call to Mass Payments via the same exact API endpoint it spins for about 30 seconds and comes back with that error about not having permission to access that endpoint.

Comment: Could that API end-point be unavailable in dev env? or do you reckon it fails in production too?

Comment: I am using that same Api endpoint for PayPal Express Payments I have integrated so I know it works from my local development environment, it just returns that error when I try to make the Mass Payments call. Not sure if there is some level on configuration that needs to be done to the PayPal Sandbox account in order to make use of the Mass Payments API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know Whether this can solve your problem or not, But this might help.

https://drupal.org/node/2215527

It basically says they have changed the HTTP API and now only HTTP 1.1 is only supported.

Due to the above change, when trying to make an express checkout payment, you get the following

```
Access Denied

You don't have permission to access "http://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp" on this
server.
Reference #18.a85e6cc1.1394550086.2c263a0 [protocol] => HTTP/1.0 [status_message] =>
Forbidden [headers] => Array ( [server] => AkamaiGHost [mime-version] => 1.0 [content-
type] => text/html [content-length] => 285 [expires] => Tue, 11 Mar 2014 15:01:26 GMT 
[date] => Tue, 11 Mar 2014 15:01:26 GMT [connection] => close ) [code] => 403 [error] =>
Forbidden )
```

It has been done very recently on Date: March 25th 2014

official :

https://www.paypal-notify.com/eventnotification/event_details?eventId=4283

Comment: This helped lead me to the correct answer. I was using 2 different libraries, one for PayPal Express Payments made use of urllib2 (Which is HTTP 1.1) and the library I was using for Mass Payments was using url lib which was sending the requests HTTP 1.0. I updated my class to use urllib2 and I was good to go and able to make mass payments from my sandbox without issues.

Answer (score 1):

You should now be able to test Mass Payments and the new REST Payouts API in the PayPal Sandbox.

You can now also request access to Payouts and Mass Payments from the PayPal developer portal.  Head over here to get started: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/payouts-overview/

And be sure to do to the My account area to request access.

Answer (score 0):

paypal api masspayment cannot be used in sandbox and must be enabled from paypal HD.
I face same issue july 2013 and i asked to paypal team.To be enabled you have to create your apps send it to them to be checked and if it respect guide line they approve it.
The best thing that you can do is call paypal and check it with them.